# Fetch works but axios doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, fetch

I have this piece of code which makes a GET HTTP request.
When using fetch, it works but with axios it never finishes.

What I tried so far is something like this:

```
getParentAssetTemplateList = async (tenantId: string, signal?: AbortSignal): Promise<any> => {
    const headers = {
      tenantId: tenantId,
      ...this.defaultHeaders
    };

    const url = getEndpoint('/asset-templates/dropdown/flat');

    // const response = await fetch(url, {
    //   signal,
    //   headers
    // }).then((res) => res.json());

    // console.log('response: ', response);
    // return response;

    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      signal,
      headers
    });

    console.log('response: ', response.data);
    return response.data;
  };
```

What I mean by finishes is, when using Fetch, the debug point reaches console.log.
But with Axios, it doesn't reach the console.log line but when I check in network tool I see the response coming as 200 OK with the expected data.

Comment: What error was returned?

Comment: No error. It just gets stuck forever. The response shows up as 200 OK in the network tool.

Comment: The `signal` parameter is not supported by Axios

Comment: @Johan It does: https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Comment: Then where is your `new AbortController();` ?

Comment: I am using react-query so its getting called automatically from the useQuery hook.
Either way, signal is nullable so even if it isn't passed, it should work.

Comment: a pending request? What version of axios are you using? Is there any installed config of axios?

Comment: I am using v0.27.2. No specific config for axios.
I did try with the latest version by the way. No help!